# Triggering a Materialized View Refresh - AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create the Architecture on AWS where a lambda function runs SQL Code to refresh a materialized view on AWS Redshift. I would like the materialized view to refresh after the daily ETL processes have completed on the Redshift cluster. Is there a way of setting up the lambda function to be triggered after a particular SQL command on the Redshift Cluster has completed?

Unfortunately, I've only seen examples of people scheduling the Lambda Function to run on particular intervals/at a particular time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways that this can be done (out of many):

1. Have the ETL process trigger the Lambda - this is straight forward
   if the ETL tool can generate the trigger but organizational factors
   can make changing ETL frameworks difficult.
2. Use an S3 semaphore - have your ETL SQL UNLOAD some small data (like
   a text string of metadata) to S3 where the objects creation will
   trigger the Lambda. Insert the UNLOAD at the point in the ETL SQL
   where you want the update to occur.